# Baracha When Tying Tzitzit to Mesh Garment

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-katan

I've read halacha concerning mesh tallitot, that the baracha should not be said when putting it on. But, does the baracha "l'shem mitzvat tzitzit" need to be repeated when tying tzitzit to a mesh garment? I ask because I offer free tallis repairs and tzitzit replacements for my congregation, and a young man who plays baseball has asked me to replace the Ashkenazi tzitzit that came tied to the mesh garment with Sephardi 10-5-6-5. I'm happy to help, just wondering if anyone can help hunt down halacha.
Thanks!

Comment: Probably depends on whether you believe that one can be mekayem the mitzva of tzitzis by using a mesh beged

Comment: Lshem...isn't a bracha ,rather it's kavan(intent) . This can be done whether you hold mesh is considered a beged or not.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question Alon. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: sam & ezra ty for clarifying! I believe his intent is to have tzitzis on at all times, so I'll say the kavan even though the mesh is not beged